# Do I have to pay my tax balance while my amended return is being processed?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, amended-tax-return

I forgot to included a sizable deduction when I filed my original return, but I discovered it and filed an amended return before April 15.  The original return showed me owing tax but with the amended return I am due a refund.  The IRS's "Where's my amended return" page shows that they received the amended return but they are not finished processing it.

I was surprised to receive a notice from the IRS demanding that I pay the tax that my original return shows.  There is no mention of my amended return in the notice.

Do I have to pay the amount due even though it is not correct?

Comment: My first instinct (though I'm not from the US) would be to see if there's a contact number on the demand letter you can call and speak to someone. Bureaucracy of all kinds is famous for one part not knowing what the other is doing, and the bit that issues demands might not be aware of your pending amendment (or was triggered before it was sufficiently processed). Of course, it's possible that even knowing there's an amendment in the pipeline you must still pay the original figure and then get it (and perhaps more) refunded later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that you sent in a return and was supposed to follow it up with the money. But then you didn't. That lack of payment has now triggered a chain of events where they are expecting money from you. You may painted yourself into a corner, because the computer system is looking for money.

It is complicated because the amount of money to be refunded by the amended return is based on the changes to the original return.

for example:

- Original return you owe the IRS $500.00
- You submitted an amended return because you over-paid the original amount by $600.

You see it as I will be getting a net of $100 back. But they see it as that you are late paying the $500. The clock for the first part started on April 15th. You should have sent in that money before April 15th, and then waited on submitting the amended return.

Talk to a tax advisor, it might be easier now to send in the money, but they will know the best procedure, form, and address.

Comment: If I had used a tax adviser, I never would have gotten into this situation in the first place.  I was trying to "save money" by using a free online site that never asked me about the particular type of deduction that I forgot.